# Copy and pasting information within a for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to create a function that copies certain excel ranges in worksheets and paste these ranges into a "motherfile".

Now, I am trying with this code:

```
Sub ranges()

    Dim month As Variant
    Dim months As Variant

    months = Array("V01 DEN HAAG", "V02 AMSTERDAM")

    Dim destinationRange As Excel.range 
    Set destinationRange = Sheets("DATASET").range("B3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

    For Each month In months

        Dim sourceRange As Excel.range
        Set sourceRange = Sheets(month).range("H7", range("H7").End(xlToRight))

        Call sourceRange.Copy
        Call destinationRange.PasteSpecial

    Next month

End Sub
```

But, I get an **Application-defined or object-defined error**. Any thoughts on what goes wrong? Thanks!

Comment: which line give you error? can you say?

Comment: Set sourceRange = Sheets(month).Range("H7").End(xlToRight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to mielk's anwser the problem is in the codeline:

```
Set sourceRange = Sheets(month).range("H7", range("H7").End(xlToRight))
```

This is because if you are collecting from multiple sheets data and you use `range("H7").End(xlToRight` it will search for this on the active sheet. Therefor it can only find the correct range if its on the correct sheet.

by using the following code:

```
Set sourceRange = Sheets(month).Range("H7", Sheets(month).Range("H7").End(xlToRight))
```

it will work no matter which sheet is active at that moment.
another addition is you can copy and paste in 1 code line:

```
sourceRange.Copy Destination:=destinationRange
```

see below the entire code:

```
Sub ranges()
Dim month As Variant
Dim months As Variant
months = Array("V01 DEN HAAG", "V02 AMSTERDAM")

For Each month In months
   Dim sourceRange As Excel.Range
   Dim destinationRange As Excel.Range
   With Sheets("DATASET")
      Set destinationRange = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
   End With
   Set sourceRange = Sheets(month).Range("H7", Sheets(month).Range("H7").End(xlToRight))
   sourceRange.Copy Destination:=destinationRange

Next month
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The possibly reason for this error is that you don't have any values in worksheet "DATASET", column B, below 3. row.

Look at this line of code:

```
Set destinationRange = Sheets("DATASET").range("B3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

First it takes the range from cell `B3` to the last cell in this column (`B1048576` in Excel 2007+).

After that it tries to offset this range by one row down (so it tries to create a range having the same number of rows and columns but starting one cell below).

However, it is not possible, because such range would have to start in cell `B4` and end in cell `B1048577` and Excel has only 1048576 rows.

---

If you want to assign the first empty row to the variable `destinationRange` you should replace this code:

```
Set destinationRange = Sheets("DATASET").range("B3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

with the below:

```
With Sheets("DATASET")
    Set destinationRange = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End With
```

Both those statements are similar. The difference is that the second one
starts from the last cell in the column B and look for the first non-empty
cell above.

Comment: thanks for your comment but the problem seems to have nothing to do with destinationrange as the selection range is higlighted => ( Set sourceRange = Sheets(month).range("H7", range("H7").End(xlToRight))) Any thoughts on how this can happen?